# generate categories tree with csv file

Tags: php, arrays, csv, multidimensional-array, tree

I need help to generate a tree of categories from a CSV file.

I tried many things, but I get lost ...

I have a file of 800 lines that looks like this:

```
"LOADERS", "S130", "Above & 524611001, 524711001 & Above", "MAINTENANCE ITEMS", "SCHEDULED MAINTENANCE ITEMS (500 HOUR)"
"LOADERS", "S130", "Above & 524611001, 524711001 & Above", "MAINTENANCE ITEMS", "SCHEDULED MAINTENANCE ITEMS (1000 HOUR)"
"LOADERS", "S130", "Above & 524611001, 524711001 & Above", "MAIN FRAME", "OPERATOR CAB"
```

On those lines,
Column 1 represents the parent class 
Column 2 is the child of Column 1
Column 3 is the child of Column 2
Column 3 is the mother of Column 4 (but it's an explode (',', Column 3))
Explode in column 4 are the mothers of 5

I would like to generate an array of this type (and created an ID starting at 50) because the goal is to convert this file into a mysql DB: s

I would succeed in having something like this

```
LOADERS (id = 50)
|___S130 (id = 51)
|----|____Above & 524611001 (id = 52)
|-----------|____ MAINTENANCE ITEMS (id = 53)
|------------------|____SCHEDULED MAINTENANCE ITEMS (500 HOUR) (id = 54)
|------------------|____SCHEDULED MAINTENANCE ITEMS (1000 HOUR) (id = 55)
|-----------|____ MAIN FRAME (id = 56)
|------------------|____OPERATOR CAB (id = 57)
|----|____Above & 524711001 (id = 58)
|-----------|____ MAINTENANCE ITEMS (id = 59)
|------------------|____SCHEDULED MAINTENANCE ITEMS (500 HOUR) (id = 60)
|------------------|____SCHEDULED MAINTENANCE ITEMS (1000 HOUR) (id = 61)
|-----------|____ MAIN FRAME (id = 62)
|------------------|____OPERATOR CAB (id = 63)
```

I tried a bunch of method and I begin to despair. Everything I did not even approaching the desired result: s I sweat on it since Monday and I want to hang myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
<?php
// generate categories tree with csv file
// http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7498119/generate-categories-tree-with-csv-file

$big_array  = array();
$temp_array = array();

$csv = <<< CSV
"LOADERS", "S130", "Above & 524611001, 524711001 & Above", "MAINTENANCE ITEMS", "SCHEDULED MAINTENANCE ITEMS (500 HOUR)"
"LOADERS", "S130", "Above & 524611001, 524711001 & Above", "MAINTENANCE ITEMS", "SCHEDULED MAINTENANCE ITEMS (1000 HOUR)"
"LOADERS", "S130", "Above & 524611001, 524711001 & Above", "MAIN FRAME", "OPERATOR CAB"
CSV;

foreach(preg_split("/(\r?\n)/", $csv) as $line) {

    list($column1, $column2, $column3, $column4) = explode('", "', $line);

    $column1 = preg_replace('/^"/', '', $column1);
    $column4  = preg_replace('/\"(?<!\\")/', '', $column4);

    foreach(explode(', ', $column3) as $column3_part) {
        $temp_array[$column3_part][] = $column4;
    }


    $big_array[$column1][$column2] = $temp_array;
}

echo '<pre>' . print_r($big_array, 1) . '</pre><hr />';

$counter = 50;
foreach($big_array as $key1 => $level1) {
    foreach($level1 as $key2 => $level2) {
        foreach($level2 as $key3 => $level4) {
            foreach($level4 as $level5) {

                echo '<pre>' . print_r('INSERT INTO DATABASE: ' . $counter . ', ' . $key1 . ', ' . $key2 . ', ' . $key3 . ', ' . $level5, 1) . '</pre>';
                $counter++;
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: The result is very interesting. But it lacks the last child. The exploration stops on "MAINTENANCE ITEMS" and "MAIN FRAME". It lacks a level (: s) But it's a great track.

For my part, I try to read the file directly using this feature. I saw that you replace the semicolon separation by commas and you put the CSV into a var.

Thank you anyway for your input.

Comment: I think there is an error, because a part of an array is totaly empty :s

Comment: I made ​​a change ... it works almost. Some elements are multiplied. Here is my code (sorry for formatting). $big_array  = array();
$temp_array = array();

if (($handle = fopen("arbocsv.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) 
{
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ";")) !== FALSE) 
    {
     $serials = preg_replace('/ /','',$data[2]);
  $serials = preg_replace('/&/',' & ',$serials);
  $serials = explode(',',$serials);
  
  foreach($serials as $serial)
  {
   $temp_array[$serial][$data[3]][] = $data[4]; 
  }
  
  $big_array[$data[0]][$data[1]] = $temp_array;
 }
}

print_r($big_array);

Comment: In fact, it works very well (modification added), it's just the CSV file that I have is borked. I post my code in 6 hours =) MEGA THANKS

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much again Ayman. Here is my code which contains the track you gave me.

```
$big_array  = array();
$temp_array = array();

if (($handle = fopen("arbocsv.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) 
{
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ";")) !== FALSE) 
    {

        $serials = preg_replace('/ /','',$data[2]);
    $serials = preg_replace('/&/',' & ',$serials);
    $serials = explode(',',$serials);

    foreach($serials as $serial)
    {
        $temp_array[trim($serial)][trim($data[3])][] = trim($data[4]); 
    }

    $big_array[trim($data[0])][trim($data[1])] = $temp_array;


}
}
```